# Email notification on any Error in MySQL error logs

Tags: mysql, shell, error-handling

MySQL writes errors in mysql error log file that we define in my.cnf or my.ini file.

We need to check manually check the error logs via tail command and fix the corrupt tables or any other errors.

Is there any shell script or method / tool through we can get current error via email ?

I mean if anything written in mysql error logs, it will send in a mail also.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the `syslog` option for MySQL logging? from there on you can do whatever with the messages that go into the system logging facility. You don't have to log to a file.

Comment: i am not expert, can you tell me the process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below bash script, which will check if there is error and will send error details in mail only if there is error.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE1=/var/log/mysqld.log

dt=`date --date='1 days ago' +%y%m%d`
err=`grep -A 10000 $dt $FILE1 | grep "ERROR" | tail -n1`

if [[ "$err" == *"ERROR"* ]]
then

errfile=/root/user/err.log
grep -A 10000 $dt $FILE1 > $errfile

echo -e "Hi,\\n\\n Please find the attached today's Error details.\\n\\nRegards,\\nDBA" | mail -s "todays error details" -a $errfile abc@xyz.com

else
echo "no error"
fi
```

If you want to send mail even there is no error then you can set mail in else condition also.

You can use mutt options also if not using mail option.

Comment: you can schedule this script in cron in morning and it will check previous date to till time if there will be any error then will send to you...

Comment: normally there should not be error in errorlog it is a rare case, so script will execute only once in a day and you will get mail only if there is error and even few lines related with error, so it is not a big issue of duplication...further you can handle it if really it is required after using timestamp instead of date check in script.

Comment: no in that one need to check the all errors or compare dates..
 i faced recent issue, i got all previous error at 10 am via cron but table corrupted at 11:45 am, so site down for all the day and error log shows error in next day.

Comment: as i updated in my previous remarks that you can check logs only last 1 hour instead of previous day and you can set cron on the basis of every 15 minutes or as you wish....

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tools able to help here. I think the easiest to setup is [Logcheck](http://logcheck.org/) which is capable of filtering logfiles based on regex.

Comment: You can define with a regex, what an error is. Based on that, it's filtering your logs and sending mails with lines fetching these. There are templates available for MySQL.